# Why scala Try-match matches Throwable as success

Tags: scala

```
Try(
  new Throwable
)match {
  case Success(_) => println("Success")
  case Failure(exception) => exception.printStackTrace()
}
```

This code print "Success"

Scala version 2.11.12

Answer (score 10):

Because

```
new Throwable
```

is just a regular value unlike

```
throw new Throwable
```

which aborts evaluation.

Comment: Thank you Mario was bit confused while debugging the code.